# Getting the last output from a stuck screen session

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I have a very stuck screen session - I can see it in screen -ls, it shows as attached, but I can't detach it re-attach it, not even with "screen -D -RR". Trying the detach and re-attach in separate commands, it will hang and never respond even just trying to do the detach.

I am fairly certain that the program I was running inside of that screen session is crashed/hung. For diagnostic purposes, it would be helpful to collect as much information as I can about what happened. I was able to get the full text of the command and options with "ps aux" (it was still running).

I then killed the process, thinking that would unstick it and return the screen session to a bash prompt (since I had started it by starting a screen session then typing the command at the bash prompt inside the screen session). Even with the process killed, the screen session still just hangs when I try to detach/reattach it.

Is there a way to get screen to let me see the last output this command wrote before it hung?

Comment: BTW, I know I should have piped output to a file when I ran the command, and I will do that in a future... but it's too late to do that this time, so I'm looking for other solutions right now!

Answer (score 0):

Attach the screen session and `Ctrl + A` + `Esc` and you can view the history messages on the console, use arrow keys for navigation.

Comment: Thanks! The problem though is that I can't attach or detach the screen session - it just hangs, even with -RR -D.